# How to apply multiple functions to numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know how to vectorize() or apply function along axis .. but my case is a bit different.
I have 1D array (z) that contains 1 or 0 and then I have a 2D array (x).
I want to apply two different functions for every row in array-x depending on the value for this row in array-z.

```
if 0 apply fun0()
if 1 apply fun1()
```

I can also build an index and then apply by index, like this :

```
ndx1 = (z == 1)
ndx0 = (z == 0)
```

and do f.e.:

```
fun(x[:,ndx])
```

but this wont change the array-x.
I would need this modified array-x for further calculations.

How would I do that ? (Somehow do inplace modification ?)
I would love if there is also a function that takes an array of functions and applies it to another array :) this way I probably wont need to do inplace modifications ?

thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slicing a numpy array gives you another view into the same data. So if you change it the values there, you change the values in the original:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,0,0,1,4])
>>> a
array([1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 4])
>>> a[a == 0] = 5
>>> a
array([1, 2, 5, 5, 1, 4])
```

so what you want is something like

```
x[x == 0] = fun0(x[x == 0])
x[x == 1] = fun1(x[x == 1])
```

A possible problem with doing these in sequence is that `fun0` might return `1` for some values. So, `fun0` gets applied and produces `1`, and then `fun1` gets applied.

If it's not terribly important that the function be vectorized, you might consider doing something like:

```
>>> def myfun(x_val):
...     return fun0(x_val) if x_val == 0 else fun1(x_val)
...
>>> x = np.array(map(myfun,x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the kind of action that you want?

```
In [19]: x=np.arange(12,dtype=float).reshape(4,3)

In [20]: z=np.array([0,1,0,1])

In [21]: I=(z==1)

In [22]: x[I,:]=x[I,:]*.1

In [23]: x
Out[23]: 
array([[ 0. ,  1. ,  2. ],
       [ 0.3,  0.4,  0.5],
       [ 6. ,  7. ,  8. ],
       [ 0.9,  1. ,  1.1]])
```

Row (or column) indexing (here with a boolean `I`) can be used on both sides of the equation, both for selecting rows to use, and rows to over write.